# Local Notifications with Data Fetching

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilocalnotification

Basically what I'm wondering is if performing a Restful request in the background then displaying that data in the form of a local notification is possible in iOS as it is Android.

For example, say you have a weather app. Every morning at 8am, the app fetches data and sends a notification to the user of the temperature. All while the app is running in the background.

I've researched quite a bit but so far have not found a direction to look into, if its even possible. Does anyone have an idea of how this could be implemented or point me in a direction? The solution must pass Apples app store inspection.

Comment: If I had to suggest and option it would be to offload this daily task to a server that can be setup via cron job to dispatch the notification to a notification server that can send out notifications to all registered devices.  That way the device does not have to determine when the event is triggered and notifications can go out reasonably in the same time frame.

Comment: That sure would be a way to go about it I suppose. I'd like to imagine iOS has some type of framework that could handle something remotely close to this or Androids sync-adapter or something :(. Thanks for your response, this may be the route I have to take.

Comment: There are ways to go about executing downloads or running tasks in the background but a lot of this does depend user driven events.  I believe that for memory and battery purposes applications are not allowed to execute tasks continuously in the background in iOS like Android allows apps to.  A good place to start taking a look at this is the Apple background refresh information: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html